# how to add spacing between items in dynamic spinner

Tags: java, android

I have created a simple dynamic spinner all I need to add spacing and add a break line between each item,also I need to know how to add more attributes like item text color,item text size......etc,by the way this spinner is created in a tool bar
and this is my Simple Code with adapter

```
Spinner navigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Prests_Name);
navigationSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same requirement so i have created generic adapter class with some extra parameters. so you can check this out and make changes as per your requirement.

**SpinnerAdapter**

```
public class SpinnerAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<T> values;
    private Typeface fontLight;
    private int color, layoutId, textViewId;
    //private int fontSize;

    private boolean IsSingleLine;
    private boolean IsFirstPositionSelectable, setTextSizeLimit = true;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<T> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = objects;
        this.layoutId = resource;
        this.textViewId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<T> objects, int color,
        boolean isSingleLine) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = objects;
        this.color = color;
        this.IsSingleLine = isSingleLine;
    }

    @Override public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override public T getItem(int position) {
        return values.get(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public boolean isFirstPositionSelectable() {
        return IsFirstPositionSelectable;
    }

    public void setFirstPositionSelectable(boolean enable) {
        IsFirstPositionSelectable = enable;
    }

    public void setSetTextSizeLimit(boolean setTextSizeLimit) {
        this.setTextSizeLimit = setTextSizeLimit;
    }

    public Typeface getFontLight() {
        return fontLight;
    }

    public void setFontLight(Typeface fontLight) {
        this.fontLight = fontLight;
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            if (layoutId == 0) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
            }
        }

        TextView label;

        if (textViewId == 0) {
            label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        } else {
            label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textViewId);
        }

        if (setTextSizeLimit) {
            label.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2) });
        }

        label.setSingleLine(IsSingleLine);
        label.setPaddingRelative(25, 15, 25, 15);

        if (fontLight != null)
            label.setTypeface(getFontLight());

        label.setText(values.toArray(new Object[values.size()])[position].toString());

        return label;
    }

    @Override public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            if (layoutId == 0) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
            }
        }

        TextView label;

        if (textViewId == 0) {
            label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        } else {
            label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textViewId);
        }


        //label.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 30);
        //label.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_small));
        if (fontLight != null)
            label.setTypeface(fontLight);

        label.setSingleLine(IsSingleLine);

        label.setText(values.toArray(new Object[values.size()])[position].toString());

        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: You Mean that I should create a custom spinner with adapter? @androidnoobdev

Comment: @Dev.7arooney no use default spinner with custom adapter and in that adapter do all customization.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help am gonna try this